# entity framework navigation property with object from database

Tags: entity-framework

Question has Author.
When adding a new question, I take the author from the database with getCurrentUser();

```
Question q=new Question();
q.Author=getCurrentUser();
context.Questions.Add(q);
```

this generates The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null. because Author already has a value for Id. How should I specify that the author is already in the database?

Comment: Did your `getCurrentUser` used its own instance of the object context?

Comment: Are you using disconnect data or are your entities connected to an object context? are they the standard entities or are you using self tracking entities? Need a bit more information to answer the question as it could be many things.

Comment: getCurrentUser is a static method. It uses the current session(where the id of the user is stored) to get the object associated with that user.

Comment: But is it using the same context instance as the method which saves the `Question`?

Comment: no, it doesn't use the same context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same context instance for both adding the question and loading the user if you want this simple code to work. If you want to use two context instances you must modify your code:

```
Question q=new Question();
User u = getCurrentUser();
context.Users.Attach(u);
q.Author = u;
context.Questions.Add(q);
```

In some cases it can be also necessary to detach user from the context in `getCurrentUser` method.